# android: Sharing formatted data using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm using this code for sharing my data using Intent;

```
SpannableStringBuilder shareBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
String input = "Input String";
SpannableString greenSpannable= new SpannableString(input);
greenSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#678a00")), 0, input.length(), 0);
greenSpannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0,input.length(), 0);
shareBuilder.append(greenSpannable);
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBuilder.toString());
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select:"));
```

As you can see in the code I use `SpannableStringBuilder` and `SpannableString` for formatting result, But when I share nothing display in the result. Am I missing something? Is Intent support for sharing formatted strings? for example when I display `shareBuilder` object into a TextView, It shows what I expected. for example for showing in a TextView I should set a second parameter called `BufferType.SPANNABLE` for `setText` method:

```
txt.setText(shareBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Now, How can I set `BufferType` for my Intent? Or What MIME type I should set for my Intent object for passing my formatted data?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

You are converting the `SpannableStringBuilder` to a `String` as you are putting it in the extras, stripping out all formatting.

Also, `text/plain` does not indicate that any formatting should exist.

Finally, while you could put the `SpannableStringBuilder` in the extras directly as a `CharSequence`, it might still be converted into a `String` on the sharing app's side, as there is no requirement that an app support sharing formatted content.

> Or What MIME type I should set for my Intent object for passing my formatted data?

You could generate HTML, instead of a `Spanned`, and use `text/html`. I am not aware of a convention for a MIME type that would actually be a formatted `CharSequence` like your `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the interface to send data across different activities, trigger the listener during certain event and listen for the event in the targeted activity